# is there a way to create PR again to other branch if the PR is already merged to different branch?

Tags: git, github

I have already merged PR(#337) to `master` branch. How can I get the changes created by this PR(#337) and create another PR to `hot-fix` branch? `hot-fix` branch is lagging from the master branch not only with this merged PR but also with lots of changes which I do not want to include in `hot-fix` branch

Comment: just create new PR from this merged branch

Comment: Thank you, Alexan for your suggestion but I can't do that because there are many other changes

Comment: other changes where?

Comment: inside the master branch

Comment: which you don't want? then create PR with your merged branch

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by `git cherry-pick` each commit from PR 337.